# RequireJS - set module name without r.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have php framework which concat all js files into one, but I use `require` and many libs uses anonymous definition. My solution for now is to include anonymous libs before `require.js` and then add definition file like

```js
define('moment', [], function () { return moment; });
```

Is there way to force name of anonymous module without `r.js`? Or maybe you know some alternative to `RequireJS` which can do that?

Comment: Why you do not want to use `r.js`?

Comment: I don't want `node` dependence

Comment: Why not? In 2015 year it's a standard de-facto.

Comment: NodeJS is standard dependency on every project? I don't think so

Comment: De-facto - it is. I can not imagine a modern JS-project without NodeJS. How do you build your CSS/LESS/SASS, run tasks, generate documentation, install third-party packages? Manually?